# Generating a report and sending out email notifications after running a PHPUnit test using phpunit 3.5.13 and seleniumRC

Tags: continuous-integration, phpunit, selenium-rc

I'm still new to PHPUnit Testing and seleniumRC, but i have managed to get them both working, so now i was wondering if it is possible to sent  out an email when the test fails and passes after every test is run. the mail should go to the developer and the testing manager. is it possible to do that? and it would be very nice to generate a whole report and sent it out on all the test results. can someone please give me a proper direction which i can follow on how to get around this.

Thank you in advance
D~~

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a few options available. For a small project,  maybe a plain php script that redirects phpunit output to a file, parses it and acts accordingly. ob_start() could also be your friend for this task.

Getting into more complicated options, you could look also into using a couple of [phing](http://www.phing.info/trac/) tasks for this.  Then, last but not least, the holy-grail: very flexible for most any build tasks and best of all  *automated* -> look into continuous integration tools such as the [jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/).

For small one-man team projects I opt for the simplest.